# Different header in different pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am going to develop a WordPress theme for my own site. It has three types of menu.

first one is only for the home page, the second one is for any normal page (like about us, contact etc.) and the third one is for article page (when a news will be clicked then where one will be gone).

how can I do this?

thanks.

Comment: You will need to create three different menus, learn about page id's and how to fetch them and finally learn about if statements to call the right menu for the right page ID

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can go about doing this.  For the `article` I would create a PHP file named `page-article.php` and within the file follow what [developer](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) tells you:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Article
 *
 */
```

and then create a custom header for the article in a `header-article.php` file:

```
header('article') ?>
```

To target the home you could use [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) and pass it `home` but I would suggest using [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) instead but you could always pass both like:

```
if ( is_page('home') || is_home() ) : 
  // further code
endif;
```

Do note this would depend on your settings as you do not mention if you will have a custom page set by the setting under `Settings -> Reading` so if you set front page you should target it with [`is_front_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page):

```
if ( is_page('home') || is_home() || is_front_page() ) : 
  // further code
endif;
```

You could always code all of this in one header.php file but I would suggest creating an additional header file and calling it `header-article.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `is_page()` function.

See full documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

```
if( is_page( array( 'about-us', 'contact') ){
//display your page menu
}
if( is_page( 'home' ){
//display your home page menu
}
if( is_page( 'article' ){
 //display your article page menu
}else{
//display default menu
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need different header in different page then you have to create a page template then you can add different header file in different page template-

Normally we use get_header() to include header.php

Now create a copy of header.php file and named it header-alternative.php

Then create a page template named "Alternative header"

```
<?php get_header('alternative'); 
/*
*Template Name: Alternative Header
*/
?>
<section class="error-page-inner">
     <h1 class="error-code"><?php  esc_html_e( '404', 'labstore' ); ?></h1>
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then header-alternative.php is called for this page template.